# how to write lots of small unions from C into Java

Tags: java, enums, union

I shall rewrite C code into Java. The core of original C code is a HW wrapper. In C we were using lots of unions for each HW register eg:

```
typedef union RegIntStatus
{
   u8 reg;
   struct
   {
      u8 bit0_abc:1;
      u8 bit1_cde:1;
      u8 bit2_xyz:1;
      u8 bit3_7_rsvd:5;
   } bits;
} regABC;
```

then we used it like

```
regABC r;
r.reg=0
r.bits.bit0_abc=1;
call(r.reg)
```

imagine there is plenty of those registers. Let say 40. How to implement it into java not having 40 class files? I was thinking to create one class like

```
univerasl_reg<T> { // where T will be some "enum"
  public byte b;
  public byte set(T bit_mask,bool val) {
    // here is compile error it does not know variable bit_mask.v
    if(val) {b |= bit_mask.v}     
    else b &= bit_mask.v ^ 0xFF;
  }
}
```

then one file can contains multiple enums like:

```
public static enum RegTst{
        b1_abc(0x01),
        b2_xyz(0x02),
        b3_klm(0x04);
        public byte v;
        RegTst(int val){
            v = (byte)val;
        }
    }
```

then I would use it like:

```
univerasl_reg<RegTst> rt1;
rt1.set(RegTst.b2_xyz,1)
call(rt1.b)
```

But it does not work because it seems I can not use enum variable .v in univerasl_reg. It yields "Java canot find symbol v". Do you know why?
Do you know how to code registers in order to have
- preferably one file
- type control between different registers (eg

```
new univerasl_reg<RegTst>.set(RegTst_OTHER.b2_xyz,1)
```

shall lead to error as I'm not using RegTst but RegTst_OTHER)
- and mnemonic for bits (eg RegTst.b1_abc)

Comment: Did you consider a `HashMap<MyEnum, Boolean>` ?

Comment: it looks interesting but unfortunately, the style of java is not having magic. generic in java, i should say, it sucks. essentially, all type in generics will result in `Object` eventually.  maybe i don't understand your problem good enough, but having 40 class files may be the properest solution if you have 40 corresponding `struct` in c.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr: having 40 classes is an option. But I think enums are more suitable and solution from Marko Topolink enables me to use enum's value.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems marko has given you a good solution. Unless you are dealing with a hardware interface (like RFID or something like that) I would generally avoid low-level, "c-style" bytewise operations in java in favour of collections, but nevertheless - you have a solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Generics are a feature of the static type system only. When you accept any `T` for the type parameter, the static type system has no basis to conclude that this type has an instance variable `v`. Your choice of enums complicates things further because enums cannot have an arbitrary superclass.

I would suggest the following:

1. rely on polymorphism and hide `v` behind a *method*;
2. declare an interface with this method;
3. make all enums implement the interface;
4. use the interface as the upper bound on `T`.

In code:

```
public interface Mask {
   byte v();
}

public class UniversalReg<T extends Mask> {
  public byte b;
  public byte set(T mask, boolean val) {
     if (val) b |= mask.v();
     else b &= ~mask.v();
  }
}

public enum RegTst implements Mask {
    b1_abc(0x01),
    b2_xyz(0x02),
    b3_klm(0x04);

    private final byte v;
    private RegTst(int val) {
        v = (byte)val;
    }

    @Override public byte v() { return v; }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Works like charm. You have saved me lot of time cos as a newbie I did not know <T extends>. I already have tried the super-class before but as you suggested it did not compile for me.